# How to debug "Unknown Server Error"?

Tags: debugging

I have full control on both server side and client side.

Recently, I am using `AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploader`. However under some circumstances, the `AsyncFileUploader` triggers browser to show an **alert box** with the word "Unknown Server Error".

I tried to locate all exceptions in `Global.asax` and tried all three major browsers (FF, IE, Chrome). But it is very strange that

- No server side exception can be found in method `Application_Error` in `Global.asax`
- No client side exception can be found in FireBug, IE Developer Toolbar and Chrome internal debugger.
- No error log in Window Event log

So what can I do for this **Unknown Server Error**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem already. I set breakpoints on all events header and run the application. Finally I found some events is not triggered which should be triggered.

After fixing this problem, the "Unknown Server Error" is gone.

However, I still don't know how to get more information about the "Unknown Server Error".